# Particle velocity measured by eulerian observer

Tags: general-relativity, adm-formalism

I am trying to understand equation 7.18 in the book "Relativistic Hydrodynamics" by Luciano Rezzolla and Olindo Zanotti. Here is the setup.

Let $n^\mu=\frac{1}{\alpha}(1,-\beta^i)$ be the four velocity of an eulerian observer and $u^\mu$ the velocity of a particle (or fluid element). According to the book, the four-velocity of the particle, measured by the eulerian observer is then,

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{v} = \frac{\boldsymbol{\gamma}\cdot\boldsymbol{u}}{-\boldsymbol{n}\cdot\boldsymbol{u}},
\end{equation}

where $\gamma_{\mu\nu} = g_{\mu\nu} + n_\mu n_\nu$ is the metric associated with the spacelike hypersurface orthogonal to $n^\mu$.
After that explicit forms for $v^0,v_0,v^i$ and $v_i$ are given, which we can easily calculate with the above equation.

I get the same results for $v^0,v_0,v^i$ and $v_i$ by following the approach in http://cds.cern.ch/record/527714. The calculation here is much better explained and can be followed easily, but the approach is very different.

However i feel like there must be an intuitive way of understanding the approach in the book, $\boldsymbol{v} = \frac{\boldsymbol{\gamma}\cdot\boldsymbol{u}}{-\boldsymbol{n}\cdot\boldsymbol{u}}$.